# Disable a checkbox if textbox is filled and vice versa in a table ( each row has 1 column for check box and 1 for textbox)

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to disable a checkbox if textbox is filled and vice versa in a table (each row has 1 column for checkbox and 1 for textbox) in JSP and once checkbox or textbox is filled, submit button should automatically be enabled.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  We'd love to help out, but we first want to see that you have put some effort into this.  What have you tried?  Coding examples are great!

Comment: That's a job for Javascript.